# Error: jsonp_callback was not called

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm trying to get a `json` of an endpoint from my api, this api use HTTP-Basic-Auth (disabled for testing). When I try get `json` the jquery returns `Error: jsonp_callback was not called`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $.ajax
      ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8000/notifications?callback=jsonp_callback",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'callback',
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonp_callback',
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(response){
          alert('done!'); 
        },
        error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          console.log(jqXHR);
          console.log(textStatus);
          console.log(errorThrown);
        }      
      });

    function jsonp_callback(r){
      console.log("function");
      console.log(r);
    }
</script>
```

I can see that actually the response the query is done and returns the json.

Comment: JSON is not JSONP. If your server is returning JSON, it is not properly responding to the JSONP request.

Comment: The following options do nothing for JSONP requests: contentType, type, crossDomain. The following options don't exist: fail, always, done.

Comment: Of course it is :/

Comment: The error you are getting suggests your server is responding with something like `{"foo":"bar"}` which is JSON, but not JSONP.

Comment: ok, and what would be the way to get it?

Comment: without changing the server? not possible, unless the server already supports CORS. otherwise, you need to change your server to properly use the callback parameter to respond with JSONP.

Comment: If you realize I have the callback apparently configured(but it does not work), the message tells me that `callback is not called`.

Comment: No, if it wasn't defined, it would have told you that instead of `jsonp_callback was not called`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: That boy so friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You must verify that your response returns the contents of JSON involved in the callback function, and not only the JSON content.

Something like this:

> jsonp_callback({"foo", "bar"});

The jsonp technique consists in return a JSON object wrapped into a callback function. And the GET "callback" parameter that You are sending is usually used to name the callback function and do it a little more flexible. By example in plane PHP code:

```
$jsonObject = json_encode($dataObj);

if (isset($_GET["callback"])) {
    echo $_GET["callback"] . "(" . $jsonObject . ")";
} else {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $jsonObject;
}
```